# I have a 2 parameter function on javascript but when I call it from cshtml, it only works when I use one parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, html, parameters

As I have already said, I'm working on a cshtml with onclick functions, particularly one of them receives 2 parameters but only works when I send one.

```
@foreach (Dificultad item in ViewBag.listaDificultades)
{
\<button type="button" id="D+@item.IDDificultad" class="btn btn-primary btnCate" data-bs-toggle="button" onclick="elegirDificultad(@item.IDDificultad, ViewBag.listaDificultades)"\>@item.nombre\</button\>
}
```

```
function elegirDificultad(id, lista) {
    alert(1);
    document.getElementById("dificultad").value = id;
    document.getElementById("D-1").class = "btn btn-primary btnCate";
    for (let i = 1; i < lista.length; i++) {
        alert(i);
        if (document.getElementById(lista[i].IDDificultad) != id)
        document.getElementById("D+" + lista[i].IDDificultad).class = "btn btn-primary btnCate"
    }
    
}
```

I tried this function expecting it to receive both parameters (id, list) but it only works when I send "ID", when I include "ViewBag.listaDificultades" in the function call it does not work. I use that "alert(1)" to know when the function is actually called.

Comment: Aren't you missing an @ in front of the second parameter? Likewise I think you have to turn it into a JS array before you can even use it like that